# Start macro by double click

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to start a macro through double clicking a cell.

I copied this code directly from the internet, but it is not working when I double click the cell C40.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C40")) Is Nothing Then
        Cancel = True
        SelectPayFreq.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

The code for worksheet events must be placed in the module for a proper worksheet not in a regular module.

[image]

Comment: And for those that prefer to Copy/Paste:  `Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal target As Range, cancel As Boolean)`

Answer (score 4):

Make sure the code is in the **worksheet code area**:

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window
4. make sure *Macros* are enabled and *Events* are enabled