# Execute macro on double click in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am not sure if I am making sense, we have an option to run macro on before double click event in excel. But is it possible to execute after double click.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start macro by double click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400106/start-macro-by-double-click)

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand the `Worksheet.BeforeDoubleClick` event handler. The definition taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.beforedoubleclick):

> > **Occurs when a worksheet is double-clicked, before the default double-click action.**

So your users will be able to double click on a worksheet and your macro can run using that as an event handler. The code doesn't run before the double click *per se* but rather **after** the user has performed the action.